# Aptana Studio Editor issues on MAC

Tags: javascript, aptana

Aptana Studio 3 is a decent JavaScript IDE for simple projects. But I'm regularly running into the same issue -  periodically the code editor duplicates code lines on the screen (not in files though) and doesn't allow moving the cursor below the last line of code. I can't seem to find any complains on the Internet about this behavior. Am I the only one who experiences this? Is there any cure?

I'm using MAC OS Mountain Lion, but it's been the same in Snow Leopard too.